# Is it possible to store a layer in a new object without instantiating via new Layer?

Tags: framerjs

I am trying to create grid where the clicked item scales up, but if there is a previously clicked button at that scale, then the previously click button scales scales down.

So far, I have figured out how to do this by creating an invisible layer without properties, and storing the clicked layer into that, but this always requires me to create this fake layer.

```
background = new Layer 
    x:0, y:0, width:640, height:1136, image:"images/bg_gradient.png"

lastthing = new Layer 

rows = 3
cols = 3

width = 160
height = 160

for row in [0..rows]
    for col in [0..cols]
        myCube = new Layer
            x: col * (width+20)
            y: row * (width+20)
        Utils.labelLayer myCube, "#{col}:#{row}"
        myCube.on Events.Click, (event, clickedthing) ->
            Utils.labelLayer clickedthing, "clicked"

            lastthing.animate
                properties:
                    scale: 1
                curve: "spring"

            clickedthing.animate
                properties:
                    scale: 1.4
                curve: "spring"
            lastthing = clickedthing
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: This is probably how I would do it.

Comment: @KoenBok I guess layers can only be created at the top level? I tried to delay creating the layer until the click event, but got an error.